# Google play store sales stats

Tags: google-play

I just uploaded my first application to play store and want to know that how google updates sales stats.

I am also curious how people will find my application on play store except the search function.Is there a category for new apps?

Answer (score 1):

If you sell apps on Google Play, you can find detailed reports of Google Wallet transactions that were processed during a month using your Google Play Developer Console. Reports available on your Developer Console show estimated sales. For final amounts and reconciliation, go to your [Google Wallet Merchant Center](https://wallet.google.com/merchant/) account.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017

There are **Top new apps** and **Top selling new apps** categories in Google Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/new, but they're built automatically.